# How to use schedule library to schedule script in Python

Tags: python, schedule

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

Date = today

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
URL = ['https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Technology-Protects/dp/B0B1VVXTKL',
             'https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Conditioner-Technology/dp/B0B1VXFLQ2']
data = []
for url in URL:
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content)
    data.append({
        'Rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[0],
        #'rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[0].replace('#', '').split(),
        'Category': " ".join(soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[2:6]),
         'Sub-Category Rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[5].get_text().split()[0],
        'Sub-Category': " ".join(soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[5].get_text().split()[2:6]),
        # ASIN 
       'ASIN': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("ASIN")').contents[3].get_text(),
        # Product Title
       'Product Title': soup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'}).text.strip(),
        'Date': Date
    })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].str.replace('#', '')
df['Sub-Category Rank'] = df['Sub-Category Rank'].str.replace('#', '')
# to local file
df.to_csv(local_path, mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

I am trying to use import schedule library in Jupiter notebook as the Cron and Task scheduler in Windows doesn't work for me. I am trying to execute this code every day at 8am. Can some one help define the job, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one should work

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date

import datetime
import asyncio

def wait_for_clock(hour, minute, result=None):
    t = datetime.datetime.combine(
        datetime.date.today(),
        datetime.time(hour, minute)
    )
    
    tt = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    if tt >= t:
        t += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
    delta = t - tt
    delta_sec = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds * 0.000001
    
    return asyncio.sleep(delta_sec, result)


async def do_that():
    today = date.today()
    
    Date = today
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
    URL = ['https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Technology-Protects/dp/B0B1VVXTKL',
           'https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Conditioner-Technology/dp/B0B1VXFLQ2']
    data = []
    for url in URL:
        webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content)
        data.append({
            'Rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[
                2].get_text().split()[0],
            # 'rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[0].replace('#', '').split(),
            'Category': " ".join(
                soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[
                    2].get_text().split()[2:6]),
            'Sub-Category Rank':
                soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[
                    5].get_text().split()[0],
            'Sub-Category': " ".join(
                soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[
                    5].get_text().split()[2:6]),
            # ASIN
            'ASIN': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("ASIN")').contents[
                3].get_text(),
            # Product Title
            'Product Title': soup.find("span", attrs={"id": 'productTitle'}).text.strip(),
            'Date': Date
        })
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].str.replace('#', '')
    df['Sub-Category Rank'] = df['Sub-Category Rank'].str.replace('#', '')
    # to local file
    df.to_csv(local_path, mode='a', header=False, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        asyncio.run(wait_for_clock(8, 0))
        asyncio.run(do_that())
```

And instead of shedule library, i using here just own code for waiting on clock (also I wrote that in "asynchronous" way, but you can also change function do_that to be sync and then at bottom, instead of asyncio.run(do_that()), just "do_that()")

Comment: thank you so much but this message poped up: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Comment: Oh, sorry that's my faul. I didn't read that you're using jupyter notebook. 
So in last lines, instead of "asyncio.run(wait_for_clock(8, 0))" write "await wait_for_clock(8, 0)", and the same in last line. instead of "asyncio.run(do_that())", write "await do_that()"

Comment: omg you are a genius. I think it's working. How should I change the cadence of the time say I want to run every minute, or every second or everyday at a particular time.

Comment: If you want to run code every minute or second - instead o await wait_for_clock(8, 0), write "await asyncio.sleep(60)", then code will be running every minute (in asyncio.sleep brackets you can type how much seconds does it mean to wait to run code)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's even work while the computer in sleep. Gotcha for the seconds sleep. Is there any way that I can change this to a weekly or monthly cadence?